# Error while converting date in YYYY/MM/DD format to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: sql, date, datetime

I'm getting an error when I try to populate an Expiration date using the following query. What am I doing wrong?

```
UPDATE E_CS_CONSUMABLE_UNIT_DETAILS  
   SET [Expiry] = CONVERT(DATETIME, REF2, 121) 
  FROM E_CS_CONSUMABLE_UNIT_DETAILS
 WHERE REF2 LIKE '2017/%'
   AND REF2 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: Is ref2 a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

Removing this line will make the syntax error go away.

```
FROM E_CS_CONSUMABLE_UNIT_DETAILS
```

This line is redundant.

```
AND REF2 IS NOT NULL
```

because of this line:

```
WHERE REF2 LIKE '2017/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datediff function instead of like statement.
hope this will help you.

Comment: Care to expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone!  The query I had worked, the source of the error was actually the date (2017/2/30) for one of the records.